# How to import new Module's in Android Studio correctly

Tags: android-studio, android-module

if i starting a project from scratch. I create some new modules

[image]

and  specify the dependencies in testModule3.

[image]

i always get the error message

[image]

what's the reason?
i know in this testProject i removed the app-module but it doesn't make any difference.

in the option menu >>Option Module Settings >> Dependencies >> add Dependencies i also can't find the modules to import?

any suggested solutions?

**UPDATE settings.gradle**

[image]

Comment: Does it show some more information of the error if you click in Show Details?

Comment: it seems like you can click on it but nothing happens -.-

Comment: can you post your settings.gradle?

Comment: question was edited